# mingw-w64 throws: specstrings.h invalid argument

Tags: gcc, mingw-w64

On MinGW-w64: gcc/g++ ver 12.2.0
Trying to Compile  https://github.com/depler/curl-impersonate-win

I get just about to the end and it chokes on minwindef.h.

I don't understand the error.

specstrings.h does exist in C:\msys64\mingw64\include\ (or gcc would have thrown 'not found' error).

Compiler calls out line 6 and 10 in minwindef.h,
I'm just not seeing the error...

I asked on mingw forum five days ago, no takers.
Anyone have any ideas?

```
Error from minwindef.h:
--------------------------------------------
windres --include-dir=../include -DDEBUGBUILD=0 -O coff -F pe-x86-64 -i libcurl.rc -o libcurl.res
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/windef.h:9,
            from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/windows.h:69,
            from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/winsock2.h:23,
            from ../include/curl/system.h:408,
            from ../include/curl/curl.h:37,
            from curl_setup.h:161,
            from version.c:25:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/minwindef.h:6:10: fatal error: ./specstrings.h: Invalid argument
    6 | #include <specstrings.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
...


First 16 lines of minwindef.h:
--------------------------------------------
 1 #ifndef _MINWINDEF_
 2 #define _MINWINDEF_
 3
 4 #include <_mingw.h>
 5 #include <winapifamily.h>
 6 #include <specstrings.h>
 7
 8 #if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION (WINAPI_PARTITION_APP)
 9
10 #if !defined (STRICT) && !defined (NO_STRICT)
11 #define STRICT 1
12 #endif
13
14 #ifndef WIN32
15 #define WIN32
16 #endif
...


First 31 lines of specstrings.h:
--------------------------------------------
 1 /**
 2 * This file has no copyright assigned and is placed in the Public Domain.
 3 * This file is part of the mingw-w64 runtime package.
 4 * No warranty is given; refer to the file DISCLAIMER.PD within this package.
 5 */
 6
 7 #ifndef SPECSTRINGS_H
 8 #define SPECSTRINGS_H
 9
10 #define __specstrings
11
12 #include <sal.h>
13
14 #ifdef __cplusplus
15 #ifndef __nothrow
16 #define __nothrow __declspec(nothrow)
17 #endif
18 extern "C" {
19 #else
20 #ifndef __nothrow
21 #define __nothrow
22 #endif
23 #endif
24
25 #define SAL__deref_in
26 #define SAL__deref_in_ecount(size)
27 #define SAL__deref_in_bcount(size)
28
29 #define SAL__deref_in_opt
30 #define SAL__deref_in_ecount_opt(size)
31 #define SAL__deref_in_bcount_opt(size)
...
```